# error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateStack operation: Cross-account pass role is not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

This seems so simple. I have ONE account, and I am getting a **"Cross-account pass role is not allowed"**` error when trying to run a Cloud Formation stack.

I am using this guide:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-eks-refarch-cloudformation

I have made just a couple of tweeks to the `custom.mk` (network, ec2 types etc).

To create the cluster, per the README, I am runing this command in my terminal, and my IAM user account is in the "admin" group with full access to CloudFormation:
`ASGAutoAssignPublicIp=no make create-eks-cluster`

This is the error:
`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateStack operation: Cross-account pass role is not allowed. make: *** [create-eks-cluster] Error 254`

Looking at the Makefile, it is using this get the account:
`aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text`

When I run that command from the same terminal it works fine --my account # is displayed.

Can anyone suggest what I might try here?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are passing the ARN for the EKS Role (`AmazonEKSAdminRole`) that you created in the `custom.mk`

You should not need to perform cross-account role passing at all, but being that the Makefile passes a default `EKS_ADMIN_ROLE` [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-eks-refarch-cloudformation/blob/main/Makefile#L23).

The role used to deploy these stack is that `EKS_ADMIN_ROLE` so if you are trying to utilize the defaulted role (within the accountId 903779448426), that implicitly doesnt have access to your AWS account and thus cannot create stacks within your account.

Comment: The README says the values in custom.mk are supposed to override the settings in the Makefile. Does not look like that is happening. The correct EKS_ADMIN_ROLE as well as all my other customizations are in custom.mk.  README says "Create a custom.mk file as your configuration file like this and leave Makefile untouched."  Yet  apparently is it trying to deploy with all the default settings in the Makefile.  If the custom.mk is suppposed to override the Makefile settings, why do the instructions then say "You may override the default values like this"  and show CLI to add vars.

Comment: The values in the custom.mk will overwrite those in the makefile. At the beginning of the makefile it imports those environment variables from custom.mk and if not provided (`?=`) it will fill in using the defaults in the makefile. You just need to make sure the custom.mk has `EKS_ADMIN_ROLE` set to the arn for the role you made in the previous step

Comment: custom.mk: `CLUSTER_STACK_NAME ?= 'gratefuldog-eks'
SSH_KEY_NAME ?= 'gratefuldog-ssh'
EKS_ADMIN_ROLE ?= 'arn:aws:iam::240195868935:role/AmazonEKSAdminRole'
REGION ?= 'us-east-2'
VPC_ID ?= 'vpc-067c79669868bb32a'
SUBNET1 ?= 'subnet-062c890e00af3eeaf'
SUBNET2 ?= 'subnet-0bb5ab25df2075824'
InstanceTypesOverride ?= 't3.small,t3.medium,t3.large'
OnDemandBaseCapacity ?= 2
NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize ?= 2
NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredSize ?= 3
NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize ?= 3
NodeVolumeSize ?= 50`

Comment: with that custom.mk, I am trying to deploy the CF with this command: `ASGAutoAssignPublicIp=no make create-eks-cluster`, but still getting the same error: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateStack operation: Cross-account pass role is not allowed.
make: *** [create-eks-cluster] Error 254`